# React-native and Redux set state and render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new to React-Native and Redux, and I'm trying to figure out how Redux actually works.

My goal is to fetch the data from db (let's say the account's that the current logged in user is following) and be able to display it in a specific screen.

I've managed to do that, set up the action, reducer and everything, but the part that I don't understand is how to actually display it in a component.

I'm using mapStateToProps to get the data from the store, and set the userFollowedAccounts to store.accountState.userFollowedAccounts . What I don't get, is I have to also pass that userFollowedAccounts into a useState in my functional componente to make it work?

Comment: could you please put your component code here ?

Comment: It's just a simple function component. I use a usestate hook > const [followedAccount, setFollowedAccounts] = useState(userFollowedAccounts), and on the mapDispatchToProps I have the userFollowedAccounts = store.accountState.userFollowedAccounts.

Comment: and also a return where I show the name of the user followed

Answer (score 0):

No, You don't need to pass the data you get from redux to useState(component state).
When you dispatch an action it re-renders your component. You can just add the data to your JSX.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by this? Sorry but I don't understand

Comment: if you only want to show the data then don't need to pass in useState just add the data to your jsx otherwise you have to pass it if you want to play with data

Comment: @flaneurx I think you should add some code snippets here